# Windows Kernel debugging with Windbg and IdaPro

Tags: windows, debugging, driver, reverse, windbg

I try to debug Windows 7 with Windbg and IDA pro but when I want to attach the debugger to IDA by click (Attach->WinDbg), it cause a error that look's like this :

> Could not initialize WinDbg engine  with error:
>   %1 is not a valid Win32 application. (000000C1).
>   Please make sure you have the latest Debugging Tools from Microsoft.

Comment: I think we need a little bit more information here. Which version of WinDbg? 32 bit or 64 Bit?  Which version of Windows 7, 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: I Use 32 bit WinDbg version and 32 bit Windows machine.

Comment: Windows 7 is in a VM or is is an actual computer on the network? WinDbg is running inside the VM or on the host? IDA is running inside the VM or on the host? Or are you attempting to do local kernel debugging? Or do you use VirtualKd? TCP connection or serial connection? Is WinDbg reachable via %Path% or not? Have you added WinDbg to your `ida.cfg` file? If so, have you escaped the backslashes?

Comment: Yes I running Windows 7 on VM and I use virtualKD, also i added WinDbg path to ida.cfg so it should work...